# Laravel - Error al hacer Migration: "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Al hacer *migration* ejecutando el comando `php artisan migrate` me sale el siguiente error:

> In StreamHandler.php line 107:
>                                                                                                                The stream or file
>   "/Users/usuario/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/proyecto1/storage/logs/laravel-2019-04-21.log"
>   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

¿Qué sucede?

Otro error que me sale al hacer "php artisan migrate" es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya verificaste que permisos tienen asignados tus carpetas? parecería un problema relacionado a ello el motivo del mensaje que nos muestras

Comment: ¿Debería aplicar un chmod -R 777 a storage?

Comment: `administrador@debian:/RUTA/$ ls -la storage  
total 20  
drwxr-xr-x  5 administrador www-data      4096 dic 15 14:37 .  
drwxrwxrwx 14 administrador programadores 4096 jun  3 08:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 administrador www-data      4096 mar  5 11:01 app
drwxr-xr-x  6 administrador www-data      4096 mar  5 11:01 framework
drwxr-xr-x  2 administrador www-data      4096 jun  3 08:06 logs`

Comment: revisa el archivo .env dentro revisa tu usuario y clave y host  para la base de datos

Answer (score -1):

El problema es un problema de permisos en la carpeta `storage/` de tu proyecto, al no tener permisos, no puede escribir en los logs y esto evita ejecutar la migración.

Con el comando `chmod -R 777 storage` ya no deberías presentar ese problema.

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo error pero no encuentro solución, y con el comando chmod -R 777 no me funciona para quitar ese error, me podrían ayudar con alguna solución si ya la consiguieron?